# C# Pacakge inside Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services possible?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

i have to process more than 1.000.000 records through several tables. I ned to loop through the records, combine and lookup for data from other tables. I have a quite complicated logic and i could do it with a C# console app.

But to have it stable and without any layers between database and app i would like to do this directly inside the database.

Is it possible to execute C# Code/Module/Package in Microsoft SQL Server or Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services?

Update:
As in the comments below mentioned the thing is called **Script Task** in SSIS!

Comment: Yes, there is a Script Task that allows you to do pretty much whatever .NET you need to do. That said, 1M rows is not much for a database to handle. If you'd like to edit your question to include those details, we can probably show you a more native way of doing such things in SSIS which should help those who come after you maintain what you're developing

Comment: I'd like to edit my question, but what should i append to get more info/native way doing such things?

Comment: Why do you need to loop through the records? What combination(s) do you need to do? What about these lookups - will you always find a match, can you find multiple matches, if so, what's your logic in those case(s), are the reference tables in the same database, same server or different server. What is the "complicate logic"? What do your tables look liked (post the table definitions {within SSMS, right click table, script table as, to clipboard and paste. Repeat for all tables in the problem domain}).

Comment: I need to create for each recordset based on the row data a new row in a static table (matrix). I cannot simply use a cross join cause i need in some cases data inheritance. For example if you are a employee of type manager level 1 then all employees below your function inherit something except employees with non-pay-scale. But employees who have no "Sponsor" get the sponsor of the person above him. I cannot simply built a sql query and i have to create a static matrix table for reporting purpose each night.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to implement your required logic in SQL if you want to explain it further. To use C# code in SQL you can use `CLR`, but to me that is a code smell - if you're using CLR you usually don't understand the capabilities of SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **billinkc**! The thing for what i was looking for is calles **Script Task** in SSIS! You can add a Script Task to your Package and do whatever you want and can do in C#!